# Using Browser Extensions inside c# - WebKit.NET or For Default Browser

Tags: c#, webkit.net

Is it possible to use browser extensions inside c# webbrowser? I want to use an VPN extension inside c# browser.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you tried? How that failed? Please be more specific

Comment: First I don't know how to achieve it because I never read of it and no source when I searched in Google. I am looking for right direction, some doc or resource how I can achieve this. I want to make a tool it needs browser addons to work inside c#.

Comment: It's just you can inject the same js another way than using the extension if you are developing one (I don't know the answer to your initial question, but it may be an X-Y problem)